# changing div height size during transform for x and y

Tags: javascript, css, rotatetransform

JS

```
setInterval(() => {
        let d = new Date();
        let sec = d.getSeconds();
        let min = d.getMinutes();
        let hrs = d.getHours();

const hourRotation = 30 * hrs + min / 2;
const minRotation = 6 * min;
const secondRotation = 6 * sec;

hours.style.transform = `rotate(${hourRotation}deg)`
minutes.style.transform = `rotate(${minRotation}deg)`
seconds.style.transform = `rotate3d(.5, .005, .6, ${secondRotation}deg)`

}, 1000)

new Date().getMinutes();
new Date().getSeconds();
```

I have a clock face image that is not directly facing the user, it is angled 45 degrees. I want the clock Hands to slightly adjust their height depending on where on the clock face they are. For the sake of optical illusion.
    When I use the code as is, I slightly get the desired effect, but the clock hand gets thinner at around 5-8 mark on the clock, and the seconds hand does not get fully extended at the 12 o clock and 6 o clock position....
What is another way to do this with more control over the outcome?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question.

Comment: I think some screenshots would really help with this one.

Comment: Also, could you not just wrap the hands in a div and rotate that 45deg?

Comment: Please show us how you are rotating the clockface  are you using 3d for example? A snippeet of code that is runnable would be useful here. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS can work in 3d so if you rotate your clockface the hands will automatically adjust their height and width.

Here's a simple example. The snippet makes the angle of rotation 80 rather than 45 degrees just so you can see clearly that the hands are adjusting depending on their position.

You will obviously need to think about where you want the observer to be positioned in relation to your whole scene rather than just in relation to the clock. So perspective-origin and position will need looking into.

```js
const hours = document.querySelector('.hours');
const minutes = document.querySelector('.minutes');
const seconds = document.querySelector('.seconds');
setInterval(() => {
  let d = new Date();
  let sec = d.getSeconds();
  let min = d.getMinutes();
  let hrs = d.getHours();

  const hourRotation = 30 * hrs + min / 2;
  const minRotation = 6 * min;
  const secondRotation = 6 * sec;

  hours.style.transform = `rotate(${hourRotation}deg)`
  minutes.style.transform = `rotate(${minRotation}deg)`
  //seconds.style.transform = `rotate3d(.5, .005, .6, ${secondRotation}deg)`
  seconds.style.transform = `rotate(${secondRotation}deg)`

}, 1000)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vmin;
  position: relative;
}

.clockface {
  position: relative;
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 50vmin;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotateY(-80deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.clockface>* {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 2.5%);
  width: 5%;
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 98%;
}

.hours {
  background: red;
}

.minutes {
  background: green;
}

.seconds {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="clockface">
    <div class="hours"></div>
    <div class="minutes"></div>
    <div class="seconds"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ! Thank you, this is perfect! I can't seem to get the clock face div to stay over top of the background on page resize now though. And so everyone else can see what the goal was here: https://ibb.co/pwDNmXw
Thanks again, really read into my request and left me with some new techniques.

Comment: You may need to look at perspective (=where the viewer is 'standing') and/or to make sure the clockface is positioned in front of other stuff (translating it on the z-axis).